# AVL pro says my Android app has a Trojan/Android.Marcher

Tags: android

I have developed an application and successfully uploaded it to Google Play Store. I downloaded an Malware Scan called AVL Pro from the Play Store as well and after scanning my phone I got the following message:

[image]

I researched about this Trojan/Android.Marcher and what I found out is that it does its stuff on applications that are not in the Play Store since my app is in there I don't know why it is accusing that. Is it possible that this is a false positive warning?

Another piece of information is that I currently have two flavors, one for production and the other for testing purposes. When I run the AVL Pro it only finds the virus in my production app.

Comment: this might simply be a false positive... in case your app/libraries not do that (which should already be pretty clear, depending on which permissions are being requested in the `Manifest.xml`).

Comment: Were you able to reach out to the owners of the app to resolve this issue?  I hit the same issue with my app and did not find any issues using any other malware scanners.